# How to move extension method on Promise to another file

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise

How to move extension method **boop** to another file and import that?

```js
export {};

declare global {
  export interface Promise<T> {
    boop(tag?: string): Promise<T>;
  }
}

Promise.prototype.boop = async function<T>(this: Promise<T>): Promise<T> {
  console.log("boop");
  return this;
};

const promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
});

const test = async () => {
  await promise.then(() => console.log("hello")).boop();
  console.log("world");
};

test();
```

If I move it to another file (`boop.ts`) and import (`import {} from "./boop";`) then I get

`error TS2339: Property 'boop' does not exist on type 'Promise<void>'`

I have been trying to add some sugar to Promise, but I'm getting stuck importing the extension methods. It works fine when I keep the methods in the same file I'm using them, but that is not really a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `boop.ts` file performs a side effect of augmenting the `Promise` prototype.

As such, there is nothing to explicitly `import`, but you just want the `boop.ts` file to be executed for its side effect.

In that case, you just have to write your import as:

```
import "./boop.ts"; // Nothing to explicitly import, just perform the side effect.
```

...instead of `import {} from "./boop.ts";`: in the latter form, Node sees that there is nothing to be imported, and may skip the execution of the mentioned file, hence skipping your side effect.

Comment: yup... IDK why it did not work before I tried this